# What are the renegade conversation options that yield more war assets value than the paragon counterpart?

Tags: mass-effect-3

For example at the end of the mission Citadel: Volus Ambassador, if you choose the renegade option, you will gain the Volus Bombing Fleet with a war assets value of 75 and lose 10 points in Turian Sixth Flee but if you choose the paragon one of saving the colony, you will gain nothing.

Comment: Or, in this case, you can use the Charm/Intimidate option to get *both* the bombing fleet *and* preventing the Turian losses, but that's not really an answer to this question.

Comment: I didn't get the option to do this >_<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>In ME1 If you choose to Sacrifice the Council, you lose the Destiny Ascension worth 70 TMS, but 4 Alliance fleets don't take losses totalling 100 TMS, netting you 30 TMS for the Renegade action.</strike>
EDIT: [You net 25 more points by saving the Council, assuming you save the Salairan Councilor in ME3.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sy6kZVuOfVQDiXf07hvCtgX2mf305W_uCT9IvA8kj70/edit#bookmark=id.gd4patbvzilx)

- Save the Council: 120 points

  - The Destiny Ascension: 70 points
  - Alliance First Fleet: -25 points for ships lost during the rescue
  - Alliance Third Fleet: -25 points for ships lost during the rescue
  - Alliance Fifth Fleet: -25 points for ships lost during the rescue
  - Allows you to save the original Salarian Councilor in ME3

    - Gives you the Salarian Third Fleet: 125 points
- Don’t save the Council: 95 points

  - Admiral Mikhailovich: 25 points
  - Allows you to save the replacement Salarian Councilor in ME3

    - Gives you the STG Task Force: 70 points

During the Grissom Academy mission choosing to use the students as Artillery instead of Support gives you 75 instead of 50 TMS, for a gain of 25.

After the Quarian/Geth war, if the Quarians are still alive, Tali and Xen argue about whether to prioritize ships for rescuing survivors or salvaging Reaper tech. The latter grants you Advanced AI Relays for 45 TMS, and seems like a "Renegade" option.

Just about everything else I can think of can be resolved with charm/intimidate or is better off with the paragon choice.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will wait a few days for more answers and if no more people write here I will accept yours.